# Any issues with HTML5 namespaced elements (a no js solution for IE)

Tags: javascript, xml, html

I recently came across **[this article](http://www.debeterevormgever.nl/html5-ie-without-javascript/)** which explains how to use HTML5 tags in IE without javascript. Basically you create a namespace globally and include it on each HTML5 tag. This way IE can recognise it and you can target it with CSS. This is the same method as used to style an XML document so if you have experience of that please comment!

In all it looks like it *could* be a good idea and a decent option (I'm quite happy to output XHTML) and was wondering if anyone had any experience with this and/or opinions.

My assumptions so far:

1. The tags are only **recognised** by the browser - they do not inherit the new outlining model
2. This namespacing works the same in all browsers - it is not specific to IE

The drawback I can see at the moment is it could be rather tiresome removing the namespacing on elements if the website no longer offers support for browsers that don't support HTML5 natively. However I think this is unlikely to be an issue for quite some time now :)

Please let me know what you all think. Even better if you know any examples of this practise that I can go look at that would be awesome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems rather pointless. The elements created are not HTML5 elements, because HTML5, served as text/html doesn't support namespacing.

So html5:section isn't an element called "section" in the namespace mapped to the "html5" prefix - it's simply an element called "html5:section". This will be in the http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml namespace, because that's where all unrecognised elements go.

Now, **IE ONLY** has had for quite a long time an unstandardized pseudo namespacing mechanism as described in the article. It does indeed create an element with a name of "section" and it sets some properties to record the pseudo namespace. And IE's parser does indeed treat it as an element such that it can be styled, contain other elements etc.

*However*, This means that you now have mark-up that does one thing in IE and something else in HTML5 compliant browsers, and *neither* are resulting in the HTML5 elements that you want.

Comment: Ah, very interesting! So by doing this the elements are no longer html5 elements in any browser, regardless of support? Effectively what I would need to do is add these elements for IE<9 only and all that that would achieve is the ability to style them?

Comment: Yes, but you'd still need to do everything twice, once for IE < 9 and once for all other browsers using a conditional comments pattern very similar to the one described in the article. If you're doing that, you would be better off using <div class="section"> than trying to use IE proprietary stuff.

Comment: Great! Thanks for clearing that up. Sorry it took so long for the accept - I thought I'd get notified when you replied...

Comment: The drawbacks mentioned (a 'html5:section' element in the default namespace, which has no semantics) only apply to content served as text/html, which you would have to do for IE anyway. Serving it as real XML will cause other browsers to use namespacing and you WILL end up with a 'section' element in the 1999 namespace.

Comment: @Nicholas - Indeed. Note, though, that IE9 also supports `application/xhtml+xml`. (real XML).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following technique to allow for both semantic container elements with no html5 functionality (section, nav, article etc) in IE AND actual supported html5 elements in all enabled browsers:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:html5="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>
    html5\:section {
        color:white;
        background-color:blue;
        display:block;
    }

    html5\:nav {
        color:black;
        background-color:yellow;
        display:block;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<html5:nav>
This is a navigation element
</html5:nav>

<html5:section>
This is a section
</html5:section>

<video controls>
  <source src="flythrough.mp4" type='video/mp4;' />
  <source src="flythrough.ogg" type='video/ogg' />
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

It won't validate, and the namespaced elements are only pseudo elements, but it seems like a good compromise.